# How to verify account

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, apple-id

I have iPhone 5s. When I try to download any app in App Store, it shows `you have not verify your Apple ID tap ok to review the instructions on how to verify your Apple ID`, and when I click ok, then it shows that verification email has been sent to my email. I never received that email, so what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You should visit [My Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com), login on `Manage my Apple ID` and modify your email settings there.